# AndroidStudio tells me my emulator is not compatible with my project, why, if emulator is api10 and project is api3?

Tags: android, android-emulator, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm running NexusOne in the emulator, with android 2.3.3 (sdk10)

My project was `android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10"` and when i try to run it on my nexusOne emulator (with 2.3.3.) it says that it's not compatible in the chooser window.

If I try to set this as the preferred emulator in settings, it will simply refuse to run and show a little alert saying it's not compatible.

[image]

i tried to change the manifest to even read `android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="3"` and still same result...

If i simply choose the emulator from the list, without selecting it beforehand, it shows not-compatible, but runs without any problem.

[image]

Any ideas why?
(P.S. I have no idea why there is this white space... feel free to edit and remove :) the only thing in this white space is the image footnotes... which should not be rendered)

**Edit: I thought I had solved the problem and wrote this wrong-answer while the SDK was downloading. But when it downloaded and I created a new AVD using android 2.3.3 (api10) the same thing occurred. Studio stills says it's incompatible.**

Android studio installs it's own copy of the SDKmanager on a non-standard place.

The stand alone SDK Manager I already had, resides at:

```
C:\Users\You\.android
```

the android studio one is at

```
C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk
```

But, AVD manager seems to save the AVD data in the same place, regardless where the SDK Manager is at. So the SDK Manager studio uses, thinks i'm missing the 2.3.3 api, but AVD manager knows where to get in the correct/previous place.

will just download the SDKs i need in both places... sucks not to be able to symlink

Comment: Are those the same AVD images you were using with eclipse? If so, launch the AVD manager and create new images for Android-Studio only, somehow they seem not be compatible.

Comment: @daniel_c05 will try to create new ones, but i created them with the AVD manaer, and that's what android studio launch when you click to create a new emulator

Comment: Correct, it's the same AVD, but when I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio, all my AVDs were showing as non-working (http://db.tt/g2Q9HCfK), although if I try to launch them from Eclipse they still work just fine.

Comment: @daniel_c05 i never used eclipse --in fact, just trying the layout editor for Studio, will go back to vim when the novelty wears off :), but i did create a new one from scratch, even started the AVD manager from the Studio tool bar, same thing happens :-/

Comment: Maybe you have other hardware requirements set ? Like hardware keyboard, screen size, etc...

Comment: @personne3000 nothing. it's the most boring manifest ever. pretty much what you get after a new project with min-sdk3 and target-sdk10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compatibility check is incorrect: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55837

As far as the SDK goes, you can configure Android Studio to use the same SDK as the one used by Eclipse instead of the SDK that is bundled with it. You can do this by modifying the `Project Structure | SDK's`.

Comment: According to the link, this is now an obsolete cause.